# Stream data from a request response into a CSV in go

Tags: go

I have something like a data pipeline.

API response (10k) rows as JSON.
=> Sanitize some of the data into a new structure
=> Create a CSV File

I can currently do that by getting the full response and doing that step by step.

I was wondering if there's a simpler way to stream the response reading into CSV right away and also writing in the file as it goes over the request-response.

Current code:

I will have a JSON like `{ "name": "Full Name", ...( 20 columns)}` and that data repeats about 10-20k times with different values.

For request

```golang
var res *http.Response
    if res, err = client.Do(request); err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "failed to perform request")
    }
```

For Unmarshal

```golang
var record []RecordStruct

if err = json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&record); err != nil {
        return err
}
```

For CSV

```golang
var row []byte
    if row, err = csvutil.Marshal(record); err != nil {
        return err
}
```

Comment: Depends on the data, can you show the code you've got now?

Comment: @Adrian I just updated the question with current snippets.

Comment: What is `csvutil`? Is there some reason not to use `encoding/csv` here?

Comment: @Adrian I'm new to Go, I found challenging performing do Marshaling of CSV properly with encoding/csv. Used https://github.com/jszwec/csvutil instead.

Comment: Can you please explain this >I can currently do that by getting the full response and doing that step by step.

Comment: @UmarHayat In other platforms like Node.js or Elixir, they have a concept of Streams that you can do operations on-demand step by step, You would not need to process the full response of the API to do any calculation, you would do that right away as you go.

Comment: @IvanSantos What type of input data do you have? Am I understand correctly it is an array with objects (actually, it is `RecordStruct`) inside?

Answer (score 0):

To stream an array of JSON objects you have to decode nested objects instead of root object. To do this you need read data using tokens ([check out `Token` method](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Token)). According to the documentation:

> Token returns the next JSON token in the input stream. At the end of the input stream, Token returns `nil`, `io.EOF`.
>
> Token guarantees that the delimiters `[` `]` `{` `}` it returns are properly nested and matched: if Token encounters an unexpected delimiter in the input, it will return an error.
>
> The input stream consists of basic JSON values—bool, string, number, and null—along with delimiters `[` `]` `{` `}` of type Delim to mark the start and end of arrays and objects. Commas and colons are elided.

That mean you can decode document part by part. Find an official example how to do it [here](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_Decoder_Decode_stream)

I will post a code snippet that shows how you can combine json stream technic with writing result to the CSV:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type RecordStruct struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Info string `json:"info"`
    // ... any field you want
}

func (rs *RecordStruct) CSVRecord() []string {
    // Here we form data for CSV writer
    return []string{rs.Name, rs.Info}
}

const jsonData =
    `[
        { "name": "Full Name", "info": "..."},
        { "name": "Full Name", "info": "..."},
        { "name": "Full Name", "info": "..."},
        { "name": "Full Name", "info": "..."},
        { "name": "Full Name", "info": "..."}
    ]`

func main() {
    // Create file for storing our result
    file, err := os.Create("result.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // Create CSV writer using standard "encoding/csv" package
    var w = csv.NewWriter(file)

    // Put your reader here. In this case I use strings.Reader
    // If you are getting data through http it will be resp.Body
    var jsonReader = strings.NewReader(jsonData)

    // Create JSON decoder using "encoding/json" package
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(jsonReader)

    // Token returns the next JSON token in the input stream.
    // At the end of the input stream, Token returns nil, io.EOF.
    // In this case our first token is '[', i.e. array start
    _, err = decoder.Token()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    // More reports whether there is another element in the
    // current array or object being parsed.
    for decoder.More() {
        var record RecordStruct
        // Decode only the one item from our array
        if err := decoder.Decode(&record); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
        // Convert and put out record to the csv file
        if err := writeToCSV(w, record.CSVRecord()); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
    }

    // Our last token is ']', i.e. array end
    _, err = decoder.Token()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

func writeToCSV(w *csv.Writer, record []string) error {
    if err := w.Write(record); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    w.Flush()
    return nil
}
```

You can also use 3d party packages like [github.com/bcicen/jstream](https://github.com/bcicen/jstream)